# How to import huge blob into SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server

I have a `.csv` file with one column of blob data type (from cassandra) that is binary data. That data can be huge - much more then 8000 bytes.

I tried to set source and destination data type `DT_BYTES->binary/varbinary` in SQL Server import wizard but failed with error that data will be truncated.

How to import such data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set column type to varbinary(max) not varbinary only, so that column will accept more than 8000 bytes. See following [microsoft link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188362.aspx).

```
 varbinary [ ( n | max) ]

Variable-length binary data. n can be a value from 1 through 8,000.
max indicates that the maximum storage size is 2^31-1 bytes. 
The storage size is the actual length of the data entered + 2 bytes. 
The data that is entered can be 0 bytes in length. 
The ANSI SQL synonym for varbinary is binary varying.
```

For integration services data types you can look to following [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141036.aspx). What you want is DT_IMAGE:

```
DT_IMAGE
A binary value with a maximum size of 231-1 (2,147,483,647) bytes.
```

Comment: The equivalent of varbinary(max) for SSIS (source data for import) is  DT_BYTES and it is limited to 8000 bytes as far as I undestand.